# Error in Google SDTT: "Duplicate values for url are not allowed."

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

[Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/#) returns for the following JSON-LD:

> Duplicate values for url are not allowed.

Why? I do not understand.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ItemList",
        "itemListElement": [{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 0,
                "item": {
                    "@type": "Article",
                    "headline": "Bonito de norte",
                    "alternativeHeadline": "Thunnus alalunga.",
                    "image": {
                        "@type": "ImageObject",
                        "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/producto/imagenes/facebook/2/BONITO.jpg?1502195043",
                        "width": "1200",
                        "height": "830"
                    },
                    "author": "SoftGalia Aplicaciones Informáticas S.L.",
                    "editor": "Pescados Trocheros",
                    "keywords": "Venta pescado, Mayorista de Pescado",
                    "publisher": {
                        "@type": "Organization",
                        "name": "Academia Lucense de Balonmano",
                        "logo": {
                            "@type": "ImageObject",
                            "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/logo/facebook/1/logo-trochero-01.jpg?1504175529",
                            "width": "1200",
                            "height": "830"
                        }
                    },
                    "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/index",
                    "datePublished": "2017-08-08 12:24:11 UTC",
                    "dateCreated": "2017-08-08 12:24:11 UTC",
                    "dateModified": "2017-08-22 07:43:53 UTC",
                    "description": "Thunnus alalunga.",
                    "articleBody": "Thunnus alalunga.",
                    "mainEntityOfPage": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/index"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "item": {
                    "@type": "Article",
                    "headline": "Merluza",
                    "alternativeHeadline": "Merluccius merluccius",
                    "image": {
                        "@type": "ImageObject",
                        "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/producto/imagenes/facebook/4/merluza-primer-plano.jpeg?1504525751",
                        "width": "1200",
                        "height": "830"
                    },
                    "author": "SoftGalia Aplicaciones Informáticas S.L.",
                    "editor": "Pescados Trocheros",
                    "keywords": "Venta pescado, Mayorista de Pescado",
                    "publisher": {
                        "@type": "Organization",
                        "name": "Academia Lucense de Balonmano",
                        "logo": {
                            "@type": "ImageObject",
                            "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/logo/facebook/1/logo-trochero-01.jpg?1504175529",
                            "width": "1200",
                            "height": "830"
                        }
                    },
                    "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/index",
                    "datePublished": "2017-09-04 11:49:13 UTC",
                    "dateCreated": "2017-09-04 11:49:13 UTC",
                    "dateModified": "2017-09-05 08:38:27 UTC",
                    "description": "Merluccius merluccius",
                    "articleBody": "Merluccius merluccius",
                    "mainEntityOfPage": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/index"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i think the error came for the url tag in line ""url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/index"," but if I change ditinct urls for each item of the list item, the error changes to "Todos los valores especificados en url deben apuntar a la misma página"

Comment: the problem go away when I change the type itemList to  BreadcrumbList `code` "@context": "http://schema.org",
'code`         "@type": "ItemList",    change to "@type": "BreadcrumbList",

Comment: the error message is correct. you repeat: `http://dechado09.softgalia.com/logo/facebook/1/logo-trochero-01.jpg?1504175529` and `http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/index`

Comment: yes, It's true. but if I put the real url the error change to "All values provided for URL must point to the same page" because this articles have url from other page. I was study the theme yesterday and I reached the conclusion that there are two ways to markup itemList. first when you have a list with urls from other pages (my case) and second when the Urls are in the same page. I'm looking in https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings#how-to-mark-up-host-specific-lists and see the markup for "Summary page + multiple full details pages".

Comment: ok, here's another idea - one that we use. reference an `@id`. while each `@id` must be uniq, a url can be shared by 2+ `@id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to implement a list format for your structured data:

- Summary page + multiple full details pages
- List item A single, all-in-one-page list

My case is a sumary page of articles, and google guide say: "The summary page has a short description of each item in the list, and each description points to a separate details page that is focused entirely on one item."

well the markup must be.

{ "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListElement":
    [
        {
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position": 0,
            "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/bonito-de-norte"
        },
        {
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "url": "http://dechado09.softgalia.com/productos/merluza"
        }
    ]
    }